# Java time-based map/cache with expiring keys

Tags: java, caching, dictionary

Do any of you know of a Java Map or similar standard data store that automatically purges entries after a given timeout? This means aging, where the old expired entries “age-out” automatically.

I know of ways to implement the functionality myself and have done it several times in the past, so I'm not asking for advice in that respect, but for pointers to a good reference implementation.

[WeakReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) based solutions like [WeakHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) are not an option, because my keys are likely to be non-interned strings and I want a configurable timeout that's not dependent on the garbage collector.

[Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) is also an option I wouldn't like to rely on because it needs external configuration files. I am looking for a code-only solution.

Comment: This question is beeing discuted on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421689/10952503) about the close reason.

Answer (score 381, accepted):

Yes. Google Collections, or [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) as it is named now has something called [MapMaker](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) which can do exactly that.

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
   .concurrencyLevel(4)
   .softKeys()
   .weakValues()
   .maximumSize(10000)
   .expiration(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .makeComputingMap(
       new Function<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph apply(Key key) {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

**Update:**

As of guava 10.0 (released September 28, 2011) many of these MapMaker methods have been deprecated in favour of the new [CacheBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html):

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(10000)
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build(
        new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
          public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
            return createExpensiveGraph(key);
          }
        });
```

Comment: I know you have just copied the example from the javadoc, but as I ran into the same requirement, I just want to make sure the map properties are correct: Wouldn't it be better to use `expireAfterAccess` (instead of `expiration`) and `softValues` (instead of `weakValues`)?

Comment: As from v10, you should be using CacheBuilder instead (http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) since expiration etc have been deprecated in MapMaker

Comment: *Warning*! Using `weakKeys()` imply that keys are compared using the == semantics, not `equals()`. I lost 30 minutes figuring out why my String-keyed cache was not working :)

Comment: How would you implement createExpensiveGraph() with a simple map-based approach that also should support .put() ?

Comment: how to implement createExpensiveGraph(key)?

Comment: @Jaskey Its just an example of a method that adds the content in the cache based on the key

Comment: Sorry, I still not understand,i guess the load(key key) is the map.get(key) method. Now, I have a map, and i don't want the key-value existing after 15 minutes of last access,  would you please implement it in a small example? Also, can I use Cache<Key, Graph> just like a map?

Comment: @Jaskey the return value from the load method is what is put in the Cache. So in this example the createExpensiveGraph(key) method could just as well return new Graph() and it would put the new Graph() in the map with the key as given

Comment: Folks, thing that @Laurent mentioned about `weakKeys()` is important. `weakKeys()` is not required 90% of the time.

Comment: @ShervinAsgari for the sake of beginners (myself included), could you switch your updated guava example to one that uses Cache instead of LoadingCache? It would match the question better (since LoadingCache has features that exceed a map with expiring entries and is far more complicated to create) see https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#from-a-callable

Comment: Is there a `graphs.remove("key")` like a map? How do I remove an entry before expiry time?

Comment: Never mind. Got it `graphs.invalidate("key")`.

Comment: @Jeutnarg I had the same question as you. As of Guava 27.0.1, if you call `CacheBuilder.build()` with no CacheLoader argument, then the returned type is a Cache, not a CacheLoader.

I'm struggling to format this, and it's Kotlin, not Java, but I hope it helps someone.

```val resultCache: Cache<String, MyValueObj> = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build()

    // elsewhere, when you have the entry you want
    resultCache.put(myString, myValueObject)```

Comment: @ShervinAsgari great answer. Do you know if it is possible to set expiration time per key on demand? For instance, I have a `users` cache, so I want regular users to expire in 30min but admin to expire in 10min. Is this doable with Guava or should I have 2 separated caches?

Comment: Is this support concurrency ?

Answer (score 47):

This is a sample implementation that i did for the same requirement and concurrency works well. Might be useful for someone.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

/**
 * 
 * @author Vivekananthan M
 *
 * @param <K>
 * @param <V>
 */
public class WeakConcurrentHashMap<K, V> extends ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<K, Long> timeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, Long>();
    private long expiryInMillis = 1000;
    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss:SSS");

    public WeakConcurrentHashMap() {
        initialize();
    }

    public WeakConcurrentHashMap(long expiryInMillis) {
        this.expiryInMillis = expiryInMillis;
        initialize();
    }

    void initialize() {
        new CleanerThread().start();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        Date date = new Date();
        timeMap.put(key, date.getTime());
        System.out.println("Inserting : " + sdf.format(date) + " : " + key + " : " + value);
        V returnVal = super.put(key, value);
        return returnVal;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (K key : m.keySet()) {
            put(key, m.get(key));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
        if (!containsKey(key))
            return put(key, value);
        else
            return get(key);
    }

    class CleanerThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Initiating Cleaner Thread..");
            while (true) {
                cleanMap();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(expiryInMillis / 2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        private void cleanMap() {
            long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            for (K key : timeMap.keySet()) {
                if (currentTime > (timeMap.get(key) + expiryInMillis)) {
                    V value = remove(key);
                    timeMap.remove(key);
                    System.out.println("Removing : " + sdf.format(new Date()) + " : " + key + " : " + value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Git Repo Link** (With Listener Implementation)

https://github.com/vivekjustthink/WeakConcurrentHashMap

Cheers!!

Comment: Why do you do execute `cleanMap()` half the time expecified?

Comment: Bcoz it makes sure the keys are expired (removed) and avoids thread from extreme looping.

Comment: @Vivek but with this implementation there can be at max  (expiryInMillis / 2) number of entries which are already expired but still present in cache. As thread deletes entries after expiryInMillis / 2 period

Comment: Can it be like, in get u check if the value is old than return null. Instead of cleanup thread. 
  as in ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63189871/3509609

Comment: @rishi007bansod True, but that's compromisable for faster gets. If your requirement demands 100% accurate expiry then you need to check and clean value on every get

Comment: @Vikash as mentioned in the previous comment cleanup thread is to improve performance of get, and values don't last in memory for longer than needed. If implemented in get and if the values aren't accessed then it lasts in memory forever.

Comment: @Vivek with a weakHashMap, the data gets removed 
1. If the cleanMap detects an item to have lived beyond it's eviction time. 
2. If GC detects items that can be removed. 
So, depending on which happens first, we do not guarantee the presence of the data. 
This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe.

Answer (score 35):

Apache Commons has decorator for Map to expire entries: [PassiveExpiringMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/PassiveExpiringMap.html)
It's more simple than caches from Guava.

P.S. be careful, it's not synchronized.

Comment: It is simple, but it checks the expiration time only after you access an entry.

Comment: As per the [Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/PassiveExpiringMap.html): _When invoking methods that involve accessing the entire map contents (i.e containsKey(Object), entrySet(), etc.) this decorator removes all expired entries prior to actually completing the invocation._

Comment: If you want to see what the latest version of this library (Apache commons commons-collections4) is [here is a link to the relevant library on mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4)

Comment: If using PassiveExpiringMap along with Collections.synchronizedMap, notice that access to the map collections (values, keySet, entrySet) will not trigger an eviction of the expired entries. Reason being that values, keySet and entrySet are "cached" in the SynchronizedMap.

Comment: implementation hint: it has a **Lazy/Passive Eviction Process**, so it removeAllExpired before performing methods, so if you don't call any methods the expired items will not be removed until you call any method on the map

Answer (score 22):

You can try out [my implementation](https://gist.github.com/pcan/16faf4e59942678377e0) of a self-expiring hash map. This implementation does not make use of  threads to remove expired entries, instead it uses [DelayQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) that is cleaned up at every operation automatically.

Comment: I like Guava's version better, but +1 for adding completeness to the picture

Comment: @piero86 I'd say the call to delayQueue.poll() in method expireKey(ExpiringKey<K> delayedKey) is wrong. You may loose an arbitrary ExpiringKey which can't later be utilized in cleanup() - a leak.

Comment: Another problem: you can't put the same key twice with different lifetimes. After a) put(1, 1, shortLived), then b) put(1, 2, longLived) the Map entry for key 1 will be gone after shortLived ms no matter how long longLived is.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Could you report these issues as comments in the gist, please?

Comment: Fixed according to your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd it's completely different. This implementation has TTL for each item, Guava uzes same TTL for all items.

On;y problem with this code is that it's not thread safe, but piero86 really thanks a lot, you saved my day.

Comment: Note that Guava is also performing clean up during write and read operations. This is not to say Guava is better, only that it works in the same way (in fact I would lean toward simplicity while Guava is massive).

Comment: @pcan: Do we need WeakHashMap for expiringKeys? An Entry in a WeakHashMap is automatically GC when its key is no longer in use. In your implementation, keys are removed manually using remove() method which defeats the purpose of WeakHashMap.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like ehcache is overkill for what you want, however note that it does not need external configuration files.

It is generally a good idea to move configuration into a declarative configuration files ( so you don't need to recompile when a new installation requires a different expiry time ), but it is not at all required, you can still configure it programmatically.  http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/configuration

Answer (score 3):

If anybody needs a simple thing, following is a simple key-expiring set. It might be converted to a map easily.

```
public class CacheSet<K> {
    public static final int TIME_OUT = 86400 * 1000;

    LinkedHashMap<K, Hit> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, Hit>() {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, Hit> eldest) {
            final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if( time - eldest.getValue().time > TIME_OUT) {
                Iterator<Hit> i = values().iterator();

                i.next();
                do {
                    i.remove();
                } while( i.hasNext() && time - i.next().time > TIME_OUT );
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    public boolean putIfNotExists(K key) {
        Hit value = linkedHashMap.get(key);
        if( value != null ) {
            return false;
        }

        linkedHashMap.put(key, new Hit());
        return true;
    }

    private static class Hit {
        final long time;


        Hit() {
            this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fine for a single-thread situation, but it would break miserably in a concurrent situation.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd you mean like LinkedHashMap's itself?! "it must be synchronized externally" just like LinkedHashMap, HashMap ... you name it.

Comment: yes, like all those, but unlike Guava's cache (the accepted answer)

Comment: Also, consider using `System.nanoTime()` for computing time differences as System.currentTimeMillis() is not consistent as it depends on the system time and might not be continous.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a cache should keep objects around some time and shall expose of them some time later. What is *a good time to hold an object* depends on the use case. I wanted this thing to be simple, no threads or schedulers. This approach works for me. Unlike `SoftReference`s, objects are guaranteed to be available some minimum amount of time. However, the do not stay around in memory [until the sun turns into a red giant](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/newbies.php#14).

As useage example think of a slowly responding system that shall be able to check if a request has been done quite recently, and in that case not to perform the requested action twice, even if a hectic user hits the button several times. But, if the same action is requested some time later, it shall be performed again.

```
class Cache<T> {
    long avg, count, created, max, min;
    Map<T, Long> map = new HashMap<T, Long>();

    /**
     * @param min   minimal time [ns] to hold an object
     * @param max   maximal time [ns] to hold an object
     */
    Cache(long min, long max) {
        created = System.nanoTime();
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        avg = (min + max) / 2;
    }

    boolean add(T e) {
        boolean result = map.put(e, Long.valueOf(System.nanoTime())) != null;
        onAccess();
        return result;
    }

    boolean contains(Object o) {
        boolean result = map.containsKey(o);
        onAccess();
        return result;
    }

    private void onAccess() {
        count++;
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        for (Iterator<Entry<T, Long>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            long t = it.next().getValue();
            if (now > t + min && (now > t + max || now + (now - created) / count > t + avg)) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HashMap is not thread safe, due to race conditions, map.put operation or resizing of map may lead to data corruption. See here: https://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html

Comment: That's true. Indeed, most Java classes are not thread safe. If you need thread security, you need to check every affected class of your design to see if it meets the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you can try Expiring Map 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ExpiringMap.htm
a class from The Apache MINA Project