# Java collection with expiring entries

Tags: java, collections, guava

I need to track certain events over a specified time frame and act if the number of events reaches a certain number. In more detail, I connect to an external service and submit requests which are acknowledged with a status that equals CONF or FAIL. I need to be able to monitor the responses to detect if I get an unusual number of fails in a given time frame, e.g. >3 fails during the last 5 seconds, so that I can check for errors and act accordingly. I could alternatively check for 3 fails in a row but I prefer a time based approach.

I have been testing Guava's `CacheLoader` after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3802370/709438) but while entries (I only store FAIL-events) in the Cache appears to expire as expected, a call to `size()` (to determine number of fails) includes also the expired entries. This appears to be how it is supposed to work according to the [documentation](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html), if I have not misunderstood things?? Is there any way to get the number of 'active' events from a Cache?

I guess an alternative solution is to use a CEP-framework like Esper but it seems like overkill and cumbersome for my simple needs. Does anyone have a completely different approach to suggest that would facilitate my requirement? Thanks

Comment: what do you see `EhCache` cache framework? I suggest see it. I think that solve your request. see from http://ehcache.org/

Comment: I suppose I don't understand the problem.  Send to external service. If error response, add to queue with timestamp. Remove items that are too old. if list length > threshhold, do something.  If this approach proves to be too slow, then (and only then) optimize.  Once optimization could be to could be to use a Map of Integers, where the key to the map is the time in seconds.  When you add an error (using the seconds as the key, incrementing the count) you know exactly which other keys to sum.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I do not see how a regular queue would solve my problem. I would need to have some sort of iterative process that monitors and removes entries which cannot be a desired solution.

Comment: @MJM Thanks. `ehCache` might work great but I do not want to read up on a (for me) new framework right now but I will keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting the exact number of active elements from the `Cache` would require locking the entire cache, which is extremely expensive.  You might be able to use the `cleanUp()` method to make sure that `size` is not accidentally counting entries that have been quietly evicted, though.

I would not *depend* on this giving you exact results, but it should improve the accuracy of the results significantly.

Comment: `cleanUp()` before `size()` does the trick! Thank you. I have messed around with an Esper-based solution that I am still testing. I will either accept this as the answer or provide my own answer depending on what solution seems easier/better.

Answer (score 1):

I think Guava collection with the nearest functionality to what you want is [MinMaxPriorityQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html) with a limited maximum size. You'd have to put failure events in chronological order and check periodically for the difference between first and last element and whether it is full.

But what you essentially want is a meter. You can try [this Meter](http://metrics.codahale.com/manual/core/#meters) from Coda Hale's Metrics library.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that a Guava `Cache` with the solution that Louis provided is a better fit as I do not need to handle the monitoring myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could decorate a collection implementation to do that. Something like this:

```java
public class ExpirableArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    private final Date creation = new Date();

    private final long timeToLiveInMs;

    public ExpirableArrayList(long timeToLiveInMs, int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
        this.timeToLiveInMs = timeToLiveInMs;
    }

    public ExpirableArrayList(long timeToLiveInMs) {
        this.timeToLiveInMs = timeToLiveInMs;
    }

    public ExpirableArrayList(long timeToLiveInMs, Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
        this.timeToLiveInMs = timeToLiveInMs;
    }

    private void expire() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - creation.getTime() > timeToLiveInMs) {
            clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        expire();
        return super.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        expire();
        return super.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        expire();
        return super.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        expire();
        return super.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        expire();
        return super.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        expire();
        return super.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        expire();
        return super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        expire();
        return super.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        expire();
        return super.contains(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        expire();
        return super.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
        expire();
        return super.addAll(index, c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        expire();
        return super.removeAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        expire();
        return super.retainAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        expire();
        return super.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        expire();
        return super.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public E remove(int index) {
        expire();
        return super.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        expire();
        return indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        expire();
        return lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        expire();
        return listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
        expire();
        return listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        expire();
        return subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but it looks like [this](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) might satisfy your needs

Comment: As of guava 10.0 (released September 28, 2011) many of the MapMaker methods have been deprecated in favour of the new CacheBuilder, which is what I have been testing without success.