# Vault configuration in springboot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, hashicorp-vault

I'm working on micorservice using springboot . I have three questions here . Answers to any/all are much appreciated .Thanks in advance

Background: We need to read some key from **vault** during application startup and save it in variable for later use (to avoid hits on vault) . There will be TTL for this value so application should refresh and take whenever new value configured in vault.

Q1 : How to load and ensure values are loaded only once(i.e vault hit only once)
Q2  :How to get the new values whenever there is a change
Q3  : How to test locally.

Comment: Have you tried using [Spring Vault](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault) with [`@VaultPropertySource(…)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/docs/current/reference/html/#_vaultpropertysource)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [guava cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) to store values (assuming they are strings, but you can change it to any type) like this:

```
LoadingCache<String, String> vaultData = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
         public String load(String key) throws AnyException {
           return actuallyLoadFromVault(String);
         }
       });
```

This way when your code will read some key from `vaultData` for the first time it will loaded using `actuallLoadFromVault` (which you need to write of cause) and after that any new access to that key via `vaultData` will hit the cached value that is stored in memory.

With proper configuration after 10 minutes the value will be wiped from the cache (please read https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen and [How does Guava expire entries in its CacheBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144194/how-does-guava-expire-entries-in-its-cachebuilder) to configure that correctly).

You might need to set max cache size to limit the memory consumption. See [documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out .
So from this our application periodically (for every ten mins) hits vault , No matter whether value in the vault changed or not  is it ?