# How the Guava cache achieve remove the key when the ttl is arriving?

Tags: java, guava

Recently,I start using guava cache in my project.But when I see the source code , I don't find the code where key removed when the ttl is arriving.

Can someone guide me a little bit?
Thanks a lot.
(My English is not so good)

Comment: I don't have the code handy but I'd assume it's 1 of 2 things: either there is a background thread that's evicting entries which are past their ttl or ttl is handled when trying to lookup entries or trying to free space if the cache gets full.

Comment: Ahh! I agree with you. And I just want to find the code in source code removing the expired key

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/10144194/869736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Caches built with CacheBuilder do not perform cleanup and evict values "automatically," or instantly after a value expires, or anything of the sort. Instead, it performs small amounts of maintenance during write operations, or during occasional read operations if writes are rare.
>
> The reason for this is as follows: if we wanted to perform Cache maintenance continuously, we would need to create a thread, and its operations would be competing with user operations for shared locks. Additionally, some environments restrict the creation of threads, which would make CacheBuilder unusable in that environment.

**Source:** https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen

Comment: I got it .I will read through the link you shared .  
 Thanks a lot