# What is the best way of defining key for @Cacheable annotation for Spring

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spelevaluationexception

If I am defining a ehcache for a method which doesn't have any parameter.

But in my use case I needs to access the my built cache through it's key.

So please provide me the better way of assigning key on it.

Follow is my code:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "cacheName", key = "cacheKey")
public List<String> getCacheMethod() throws Exception{
```

P.S. I am getting the following error when I am trying to access this method from somewhere else.

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: 
>   EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'cacheKey' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject'

Comment: Well, there are no parameters in your method signature, so even if `key="cacheKey"` *was* a valid SpEL ([it isn't](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key)) it wouldn't work since there's no such parameter. Hard to tell what you're hoping to achieve since it isn't how `@Cacheable` works - it *does* need method paramaters to use as keys, otherwise the cache will have the capacity of one item.

Comment: you are absolutely correct with the @Cacheable annotation, when i try to access the cache programmatically it's returning the correct object and also if i am trying to access from same class it's working fine, but when i try to access the method from another class its throw the error "EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'cacheKey' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject'"

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking (you seem to have changed the direction of your question three times), sounds like it could be related to THIS problem → http://stackoverflow.com/q/12115996/1240557 ?

Comment: Kryger you almost get it what i am asking, i have solved the problem of proxies by accessing the cache programmatically                 Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("cacheName");                  if (cache.get("cacheKey") != null) {
return (List<String>) cache.get("cacheKey").get();
}                                                                 and its work fine in same class but when it comes for accessing the cached method from different class it throws the spring spel exception

Comment: Have you tried removing `key` from the annotation configuration? As per my first comment it's incorrect for more than one reason. However, it's not clear what's the meaning of the `"cacheKey"` string in the snippet you included in your comment above and how you expect it to be related to the `@Cacheable` annotation. Are you *sure* you read the documentation?

Comment: kryger i think you might be correct, but as can in my previous comment i have to access the cached List<String> from cache object, there i am trying to get the cache object without key then i am getting only null.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The method has no parameter, therefore there is no a way to use a parameter/argument as a default key, and you can't use "static text" as a Key, you could do the following:

Declare the following

```
public static final String KEY = "cacheKey";
```

- must be `public`
- must be `static` and `final`

Then

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "cacheName", key = "#root.target.KEY")
public List<String> getCacheMethod() throws Exception{
```

Done

Comment: any impact of adding key to cacheable annotation ?

Answer (score 7):

In simple cases you can use an easier way: `@Cacheable(key = "#root.methodName")`, and the key would be equal to annotated method's name

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this using a single quote in the key that makes it String again.

```
@Cacheable(value= CACHE_NAME.PRODUCT_CATLOG, key=" 'products' ")
    public List<Product> findAll() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(productRepository.findAll().spliterator(),false).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

the key refers to the arguments of your method, you are having `SpelEvaluationException` because `cachekey` isn't among your method arguments.

Comment: ShadowRay i want to create a key when there is no argument, Can we do it? Or not