# Caching lookups on application startup doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-cache

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.9 on Tomcat 9.0.2 and I am trying to cache lookups using spring **@Cacheable** scheduling a cache refresh job that runs on application startup and repeats every 24 hours as follows:

```
@Component
public class RefreshCacheJob {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RefreshCacheJob.class);

    @Autowired
    private CacheService cacheService;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000 * 24, initialDelay = 0)
    public void refreshCache() {
        try {
            cacheService.refreshAllCaches();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in RefreshCacheJob", e);
        }
    }

}
```

and the cache service is as follows:

```
@Service
public class CacheService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheService.class);

    @Autowired
    private CouponTypeRepository couponTypeRepository;

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = Constants.CACHE_NAME_COUPONS_TYPES, allEntries = true)
    public void clearCouponsTypesCache() {}

    public void refreshAllCaches() {
        clearCouponsTypesCache();
        List<CouponType> couponTypeList = couponTypeRepository.getCoupons();
        logger.info("######### couponTypeList: " + couponTypeList.size());
    }
}
```

the repository code:

```
public interface CouponTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<CouponType, BigInteger> {
    @Query("from CouponType where active=true and expiryDate > CURRENT_DATE order by priority")
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = Constants.CACHE_NAME_COUPONS_TYPES)
    List<CouponType> getCoupons();
}
```

later in my webservice, when trying to get the lookup as follows:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Path("/getCoupons")
@ApiOperation(value = "")
public ServiceResponse getCoupons(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @HeaderParam("lang") String lang) throws Exception {
    try {
        List<CouponType> couponsList = couponRepository.getCoupons();
        logger.info("###### couponsList: " + couponsList.size());
        return new ServiceResponse(ErrorCodeEnum.SUCCESS_CODE, resultList, errorCodeRepository, lang);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in getCoupons webservice: ", e);
        return new ServiceResponse(ErrorCodeEnum.SYSTEM_ERROR_CODE, errorCodeRepository, lang);
    }
}
```

The first call it gets the lookup from the database and the subsequent calls it gets it from the cache, while it should get it from the cache in the first call in the web service?

Why am I having this behavior, and how can I fix it?

Comment: the caching annotation creates a proxy around the service. `refreshAllCaches` however bypasses this proxy and calls the method directly within the service. the solution is to call `clearCouponsTypesCache` from a different service

Comment: Is `@EnableScheduling` present on the application config class?

Comment: yes it's enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was fixed after upgrading to **Tomcat 9.0.4**

Answer (score 1):

While it's not affecting the scheduled task per se, when `refreshAllCaches()` is invoked in the `CacheService`, `@CacheEvict` on `clearCouponsTypesCache()` is bypassed since it's invoked from the same class (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12116107/5784273) answer). It will lead to cache not being purged before

```
List<CouponType> couponTypeList = couponTypeRepository.getCoupons();
```

is invoked. This means that the `@Cacheable` `getCoupons()` method will not query the database, but will instead return values from the cache.

This makes the scheduled cache refresh action to do its work properly only once, when the cache is empty. After that it's useless.

The `@CacheEvict` annotation should be moved to `refreshAllCaches()` method and add `beforeInvocation=true` parameter to it, so the cache is purged *before* being populated, not after.

---

Also, when using Spring 4 / Spring Boot 1.X, these bugs should be taken into consideration:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8331
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15271

While this bug doesn't seem to affect this specific program, it might be a good idea to separate `@Cacheable` annotation from `JpaRepository` interface until migration to Spring 5 / Spring Boot 2.X.

Answer (score 0):

`@CacheEvict` won't be invoked when called within the same service. This is because Spring creates a proxy around the service and only calls from "outside" go through the cache proxy.

The solution is to either add

`@CacheEvict(cacheNames = Constants.CACHE_NAME_COUPONS_TYPES, allEntries = true)`

to `refreshAllCaches` too, or to move `refreshAllCaches` into a new service that calls `ICacheService.clearCouponsTypeCache`.

Comment: you are not getting the issue, the issue isn't about the cache not getting cleared, it's the other way around