# why @Cacheable is invalid, when I Indirect invoke method?

Tags: spring, caching, annotations, invoke

### @Cacheable @CacheEvict invalid

I has a service like this:

```
@service
pubic class TestService {

  @Cacheable(cacheNames ="user",key = "#userId")
  public User fetchUserById(Long userid) {
       return new User();
  }

  public User fetchCurrentUser() {
      return fetchUserById(124L);
  }
}
```

there is some problem:

`@Cacheable` is valid, when I invoke `fetchUserById(Long userid)`.

but `@Cacheable` is invalid, when I invoke `fetchCurrentUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution here : [Spring cache @Cacheable method ignored when called from within the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115996/spring-cache-cacheable-method-ignored-when-called-from-within-the-same-class)

> This is because of the way proxies are created for handling caching,
> transaction related functionality in Spring. This is a very good
> reference of how Spring handles it - Transactions, Caching and AOP:
> understanding proxy usage in Spring
>
> In short, a self call bypasses the dynamic proxy and any cross cutting
> concern like caching, transaction etc which is part of the dynamic
> proxies logic is also bypassed.
>
> The fix is to use AspectJ compile time or load time weaving.