# How does @Cacheable work if you use it with the same value for methods with different numbers of arguments?

Tags: kotlin, caching, redis

I have a kotlin spring data application with redis caching.

My methods with caching look like that:

```
@Cacheable("bubbles")
override fun findAllByProductType(type: ProductType): List<Bubble> {
    return repository.findAllByProductType(type)
}

@Cacheable("bubbles")
override fun getByProductTypeAndBubbleId(type: ProductType, bubbleId: Long): Bubble {
    return repository.findByProductTypeAndBubbleId(type, bubbleId)
        ?: throw BubbleNotFoundException.byId(bubbleId)
}

@CacheEvict("bubbles")
override fun saveAll(bubbles: List<Bubble>): List<Bubble> {
    val entities = bubbles.map { mapper.mapToEntity(it) }.toList()
    return repository.saveAll(entities)
}
```

But I have some doubts that this will actually work correctly, since the first and second methods (`findAllByProductType` and `getByProductTypeAndBubbleId`) have a different number of arguments. Will the data from them be located in one Redis table? And there are doubts that the methods with `@CacheEvict` (`saveAll`) will work for both of them. Guru of caching and radish in particular, please help

Answer (score 1):

If you have two methods providing access to essentially the same objects, Spring does not know this, so if callers to the class asked for :

1. `getByProductTypeAndBubbleId(a, 1)`
2. `findAllByProductType(a)`
3. `getByProductTypeAndBubbleId(a, 1)`

you will end up with 2 elements in the cache, one keyed by `{a, 1}` the other by `{a}`.  Indeed the returns from your methods are different.  So the cache will "work" ... in that it will cache, but the two methods (as written) will not be sharing the same stored data, so it won't be as efficient as your might have hoped.

The eviction will not work - as nothing is likely to match the key, you need to think carefully about which elements you are trying to evict.

You should read about [Key Generation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/cache/annotations.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key)

If your aim is to avoid reading `Bubble`s from the repository then (and this is because it is some expensive operation), and if you can reliably group the read operation for a `ProductType` then I think I would concentrate on only caching

```
@Cacheable("bubbles")
override fun findAllByProductType(type: ProductType): List<Bubble> {
    return repository.findAllByProductType(type)
}
```

and then re-write the other finder to be something like this (with no @Cacheable annotation) - so that this method *uses* the other cached method:

```
override fun getByProductTypeAndBubbleId(type: ProductType, bubbleId: Long): Bubble {
    return findAllByProductType(type).firstOrNull { it.id == bubbleId }
        ?: throw BubbleNotFoundException.byId(bubbleId)
}
```

But care is needed here, because you cannot put those two methods in the same class, because by default the caching behaviour will not take place INSIDE the class. Read this Question to find out why: [Spring cache @Cacheable method ignored when called from within the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12115996/1847378)