# LRU cache on top of shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, linkedhashmap, lru

I would like to create an LRU cache that is backed by the shared preferences. Basically I would like to store a specific number of strings (around 20) and have an LRU behavior.
I know that `LinkedHashMap` is an LRU in java but is there a way to achieve what I want somehow backing up the LRU in the shared preferences in a clean way?

Comment: if you're using Guava, they've got maps with delegating load events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802370/java-time-based-map-cache-with-expiring-keys

Comment: @eduyayo: I am not using Guava.

Comment: You can add a timestamp to each keys or values, call `mSharedPreferences.getAll()` to see al the keys and values and use `remove().commit()` to get rid of the last one. Should be fast enough as long as you don't have too many elements.

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way would be, maintain a `LinkedHashMap` in the application. When ever there is a any operation on `LinkedHashMap`, convert it into String ArrayList and save it into SharedPreferences and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes I am fine with the LinkedHashMap. My question is how would I "glue" the LinkedHashMap with the SharedPreferences in a clean way

Comment: You can save it as a single arraylist

Comment: You have to write a wrapper function which will push linkedhashmap into shared preference and read it back

Comment: When exactly should this commits occur though? When should the linked hashmap should be created in the activity lifecycle and when should an update to the linkedhashmap should commit to the shared preference?

Comment: You can create it on onCreate and and can write it on onStop

Comment: In your answer you recommend to convert and save on any alteration of the LRU though

Comment: It depends on your application..If you are using it for single activity than its recommend it do it on activity life cycle method
 Buy if you are using across application than you should so it on alteration