# Update String Variable in java only if required

Tags: java, string, bearer-token

I am currently storing my access token in a string

```
String token = getAccessToken();
conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

I am testing a piece of code that creates million of users. Each time when I make a post call, I need to set authorization, the authorization obtained once are valid for 1 hour.

Is there a way I can store this token for 1 hour and only when I get authorization exception, I again make a call to get the token stored back to the string.

Currently I am making this call prior to a get/post call to search and create user.

Comment: getAccessToken()

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802370/java-time-based-map-cache-with-expiring-keys, which was closed as off-topic.