# A durable cache for event streams with customized expiration in Java

Tags: java, caching, data-structures, hashmap, timestamp

I want to implement a lightweight caching data structure in Java, in code. I was primarily thinking about implementing something from scratch with `HashMap`, but thought there might be available solutions.

The cache will be between the application and the database layer, and I will probably update it every `5` minutes. The data are all in JSON format, containing series of events with `timestamp`. The expiration rule is that I want the cache to only include events whose `timestamp` are within say `[-10min, +10min]` from current time of insertions, not the time of insertion (I might insert multiple data at the same time to cache, however their timestamp might be different). So basically everytime I grabbed some data from database, I will need to do some JSON processing and insert/update the cache. It can be up to a few thousand JSON files so my scale is not very large.

What would be the best way to implement this cache? What data structure would you recommend to use?

**UPDATE:**
Few things to note:

- **Data Structure:** The data events I grabbed from database are sorted in time (hundreds of timed event streams per each call). So my cache would be actually a time window of events. It keeps events of `[-10min, +10min]` of current time at insertion (every 5 minutes).
- **Insertion:** As the data events I grabbed from database are sorted in time. So I'm not sure if I should erase the whole cache and insert my new event streams, or pass the events to the cache and it will take care of updating itself given the timestamps.
- **Retrieval:** To do a retrieval, now I need to retrieve the series of events falling into a `[start_time, end_time]` interval which is a subset of my cache data (so these values are less than `10 minutes`). So consider that when suggesting the right data structure.

Comment: You can take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802370/java-time-based-map-cache-with-expiring-keys

Comment: try google guava cache

Comment: [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) supports a custom [expiration policy](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#time-based) which is amortized O(1) ([hierarchical timer wheel](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-purgatory-hierarchical-timing-wheels/)).

Comment: Thanks. Will look at these. Please also look at my update in the question.

Comment: If you are reloading every 5m, you could just use a volatile `Map` field and replace it in one shot. The map itself would be unmodifiable, as you swap it rather than update. If that's all you need then a caching library is probably overly complex.

Comment: @BenManes Right, I don't think we need something complex. A HashMap is totally fine. But idk how to do the data only with a subset time window. Should I get all items and just iterate over them and choose the ones falling within the window?!

Comment: Yes, but if you only need those from the database you should write the SQL to only load that subset.

Comment: Well, the notion is to somehow cache a larger portion locally.

Comment: writing your self is okay as a learning exercise but for a serious app always use battle tester library code like guava cache or mapdb cache that let's you offload to local disk.

Comment: @TinaJ Yes, I meant your db retrieval query to populate the cache could return only the subset in the time range (e.g. `between` operator). Regardless, you could store into a `NavigableMap<timestamp, List<event>>` for efficient range lookups.