# Extracting a list out of NavigableMap

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, treemap, concurrenthashmap

This is a follow-up question from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228875).

I'm trying to implement a `NavigableMap` defined as `NavigableMap<Timestamp, Event>`. I would need this map to be like a cache for me. Every 5 minutes I refresh this `NavigableMap`.

One thread updates this `NavigableMap`, and another one reads from it, so it needs to be thread-safe. Whenever I have a request, I would need to grab a subset list of `Events` whose timestamps are within a given `start` and `end` time.

What is the most efficient way to convert a `NavigableMap` to this subset list, say `ArrayList`? And what's the thread-safe implementation of this interface?

Apparently `NavigableMap` has a sub-map method as well as `floor` and `ceiling`, but I don't see anything to convert to a list with a start and end time.

Comment: Is this a local ArrayList?

Comment: What do u mean local?!

Comment: I think yes. The requesting thread would need to generate a local arraylist and consume it locally.

Answer (score 2):

To extract a key-range from the [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), call [`subMap(K fromKey, K toKey)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap-K-K-) or [`subMap(K fromKey, boolean fromInclusive, K toKey, boolean toInclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap-K-boolean-K-boolean-).

If you just want the values, as a list, do this:

```
List<Event> list = new ArrayList<>(map.subMap(start, end).values());
```

---

> what's the thread-safe implementation of this interface?

According to the [**javadoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html): [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)

Comment: `subMap` is just a *view* of the underlying map, so its time complexity is just `O(1)`. Fetching its first element would be `O(logN)`, though. Then, it's just a traversal. So, copying the submap to i.e. an `ArrayList` would be `O(logN + M)`, with `N` being the total number of entries in the map and `M` the number of elements within the given range. Be careful with `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, as bulk operations require external synchronization, and especially because its `size()` method has `O(N)` time complexity. @TinaJ

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference if I use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` or `synchronized{treeMap}`?!

Comment: Yes. `synchronized{treeMap}` does not synchronize iterations, so you have to do that yourself, i.e. during the `new ArrayList<>(submap)` call, and `synchronized` is likely slower than `ConcurrentSkipListMap`