# Kotlin Guava Cache not showing right hitCount

Tags: java, caching, kotlin, guava

I'm trying to use an LRU cache as shown here [Java time-based map/cache with expiring keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802370/java-time-based-map-cache-with-expiring-keys)

My code:

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

fun main(args: Array<String>) {


val cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100).
    expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    .build<String, String>()


    cache.put("a", "blah")
    val x = cache.getIfPresent("a")
    cache.stats().also { println(it) }
    println(x)

}
```

Output:

```
CacheStats{hitCount=0, missCount=0, loadSuccessCount=0, loadExceptionCount=0, totalLoadTime=0, evictionCount=0}
blah
```

I was expecting `hitCount` to be 1, rather than 0.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing [`.recordStats()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#recordStats--) call on `CacheBuilder`:

> Enable the accumulation of `CacheStats` during the operation of the cache. Without this `Cache.stats()` will return zero for all statistics.