# Create a Set<String> whose elements expire by time

Tags: java

Here is a situation. I have a non blocking stream of `String`. These `String`s can repeat so I want to setup a cache that keeps the record of last 10 seconds of `String` that were recieved. After enabling the cache the system's network has improved drastically but at the cost of performance. Here is what I am using to cache:

```
@Getter
@ToString
class StringWrapper implements Comparable<StringWrapper> {
    private String string;
    private long time;
    private StringWrapper() {}
    public StringWrapper(String string) {
        this();
        this.string = string;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(StringWrapper o) {
        return getTime() > o.getTime() ? 1 : getTime() < o.getTime() ? -1: 0;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof StringWrapper)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
        StringWrapper sw = (StringWrapper) obj;
        return string.equals(sw.getString());
    }
}

class SetProxy extends HashSet<StringWrapper> {
    private interface Thunk { public void exec(); }
    // expire by ten second
    private final Thunk thunk = () -> removeIf(sw -> System.currentTimeMillis() - sw.getTime() > 1000 * 10);
    @Override
    public boolean add(StringWrapper e) {
        thunk.exec();
        return super.add(e);
    }
    //... similar method overrides that invoke thunk internally
}
```

I have to invoke `thunk.exec()` on each method that add or removes from the `Set` otherwise the memory consumption will increase. The problem is with `removeIf` inside `thunk#exec`, it iterates over the set again and again.

I thought of having a seperate scheduler that executes every one second to remove the expired `String` but it comes along with concurrency problems.

Can someone suggest a better workaround?

Comment: Why have your separate scheduler execute every 1 sec. Why not have a ScheduledExecutorService that calls remove in the allotted timeout. What do you mean by "at the cost of performance"?

Comment: @matt `thunk#exec` executes on each `add`, this steals some computation cycles because there are nearly 2K string received each second.

Comment: How about Guava? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802420/2067492 Also,  you've left off the thunk.exec() method. It sounds like thunk.exec is for removing the expired entries?

Comment: @matt Perfect. Thanks for it. And yes, `thunk#exec` is removing the expired entries.