# How can I organize the removal of elements from the Map by timer?

Tags: java

[There is no answer to my question here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802370/java-time-based-map-cache-with-expiring-keys)

For example, there is a ,

```java
Map <K,V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()
```

**V** - some object that can be in the **Map** for no more than **300 ms**. When we add an element to the **Map** (or it could be a **Queue** data structure), a **timer** would be turned on, which would delete the element after **300 ms**.

At the same time, if an element is in this primitive cache, then when accessing it, you need to update the **timer** for this object (that is, start counting from the beginning, for this requested object).

In fact, this is an **LRU cache**, it has a certain **size**, removes the least used element from it (I know how to do this part), but at the same time, **each** serviced **element** must have an independent **timer** that will **remove** such an **element** from this **cache**, and when such **element** (in that **cache**) updating, the **timer** for such an element must be reset to zero, and if no one requires the **item** during the specified time, the **element** is automatically **deleted** from the **cache**.

Who has any ideas how this could be organized?

Comment: I don't agree with you. You hurried to close the question without even getting into it. This question is not a duplicate. You're wrong.

Comment: I see it exactly as a use case of https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#expireAfterWrite(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) . Anyway, if you cannot use 3rd party libs, this can be done with a `Map <K,java.util.Timer>` maintained parallel to your values map.