# How can I organize the removal of elements from the Map by timer (standalone)?

Tags: java

[There is no answer to my question here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802370/java-time-based-map-cache-with-expiring-keys)

For example, there is a ,

```java
Map <K,V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()
```

**V** - some object that can be in the **Map** for no more than **300 ms**. When we add an element to the **Map** (or it could be a **Queue** data structure), a **timer** would be turned on, which would delete the element after **300 ms**.

At the same time, if an element is in this primitive cache, then when accessing it, you need to update the **timer** for this object (that is, start counting from the beginning, for this requested object).

In fact, this is an **LRU cache**, it has a certain **size**, removes the least used element from it (I know how to do this part), but at the same time, **each** serviced **element** must have an independent **timer** that will **remove** such an **element** from this **cache**, and when such **element** (in that **cache**) updating, the **timer** for such an element must be reset to zero, and if no one requires the **item** during the specified time, the **element** is automatically **deleted** from the **cache**.

Who has any ideas how this could be organized?

Comment: Just a note, I recommend reducing the amount of bold you use.  The more bold characters you use, the less it means and the harder it is to actually read your question.

Comment: @skyho Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. Also explain how the several solutions from the linked question does not solve your problem.

Comment: If I had to write it myself, I'd most probably write a class implementing `Map<K, V>`, and managing an internal `Map<K, TimedEntity<V>>`. I'd most probably only delete entries when they are queried and timed-out, or when a new entry should be added, but capacity is reached.

Comment: Bluntly, this problem is much too hard to solve in a StackOverflow answer.  Use an existing library like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine).

Comment: [Does this help in any way?](https://gist.github.com/pcan/16faf4e59942678377e0)

Comment: Perhaps [`ExpiringMap`](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap#expiration-policies). (I’ve not used it.)