# Preventing concurrent executions of a java method based on a key

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I'm working on a java application that needs to submit post requests to an external API. The problem I'm running into is that if the event that executes the method is trigger more than once (such as if the user accidently double clicks) we end up with duplicate data being submitted to the external system.

What I need is a way to store an identifying key such as an ID when the method is called and then prevent any additional calls with that key until the current execution is finished.

For reference, my function looks like this:

```
public static SendCreateMessageResponse createMessage(String baseUrl, String application, String env, String type, String channel, String modoToken, Message message, ArrayList<ChannelDatum> personalChannels) {


            PersonalMessageRequest pemr = null;

            pemr = new PersonalMessageRequest();
            PersonalMessage pm = new PersonalMessage();
            pm.setTitle(message.getTitle());
            pm.setBody(message.getBody());
            
            logger.debug("Send message to modo: " + pm);
            pemr.setPersonal_message(pm);
            
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = null;
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        Response response = null;
        try {
            if(pmr!=null) {
                logger.debug(om.writeValueAsString(pmr));
                body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, om.writeValueAsString(pmr));
            } 
            
            logger.info("Calling URL: "+baseUrl+application+"/"+env+"/"+type+"/channels/"+channel+"/messages");
            logger.trace("Sending data: " + body);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
              .url(baseUrl+application+"/"+env+"/"+type+"/channels/"+channel+"/messages")
              .method("POST", body)
              .addHeader("accept", "application/vnd.modo.communicate.v2")
              .addHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
              .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+modoToken)
              .build();
//Note that this is not asynchronous. execute will block until the response returns or //fails
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
            logger.debug(jsonResponse);
            SendCreateMessageResponse messagesResponse = om.readValue(jsonResponse, SendCreateMessageResponse.class);
            return messagesResponse;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error creating message", e);
        } finally {
            if(response!=null) {
                if(response.body()!=null) {

                        response.body().close();
                }               
            }
        }       
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered doing this clientside? Eg deactivate the button for one second after it's clicked.

Comment: Also, how many instances of the app are there?  If > 1, then will need to coordinate across VMs.

Comment: @lance-java Ideally I would do this clientside but I am limited in what I can do with the interface.

Comment: What GUI framework?

Comment: If possible, consider implementing [idempotency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Comment: additional to @Bohemian's comment, I include another source about idempotency (with a less mathematical approach and a more porgramming-oriented one): [idempotency example](https://medium.com/@scottietom/idempotence-what-is-it-and-why-should-i-care-29f8ff265186#:~:text=idempotency%20at%20all.-,Conclusion,-Being%20idempotent%20is)

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is known as `debouncing`. You could write a simple debouncer in java backed by a `ScheduledExecutorService` which holds onto a cache for a period of time.

```java
public class Debouncer {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;
   private final long duration;
   private final TimeUnit unit;
   private final ConcurrentMap<Object, Future<Object>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   
   // constructor

   public Object debounce(Object key, Callable<Object> callable) throws Exception {
      Function<Object, Future<Object>> function = k -> {
          // submit the "work" to be performed asynchronously
          Future<Object> future = executor.submit(callable);

          // schedule the future removal of the cache entry
          executor.schedule(() -> cache.remove(k), duration, unit);

          return future;
      };

      // above tasks will only be submitted if the key absent from the map
      Future<Object> future = cache.computeIfAbsent(key, function);

      // possibly wait for asynchronous work, possibly return immediately
      return future.get();
   }
}
```

Let's assume you have the following API

```java
public interface Api {
   String methodOne(String arg1, String arg2);
   Date methodTwo(Long arg1);
}
```

You could wrap it with

```java
public class DebouncingApi implements Api {
   private final Api delegate;
   private final Debouncer debouncer;

   // constructor

   public String methodOne(String arg1, String arg2) {
      List<Object> key = List.of("methodOne", arg1, arg2);
      return (String) debouncer.debounce(key, () -> delegate.methodOne(arg1, arg2));
   }

   public Date methodTwo(Long arg1) {
      List<Object> key = List.of("methodTwo", arg1);
      return (Date) debouncer.debounce(key, () -> delegate.method2(arg1));
   }
}
```

Note: Each method arg needs to implement `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)`

I'm sure there's also some caches in [guava](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache) which could help with this but since it's so simple perhaps not worth the overhead of adding the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

> trigger more than once (such as if the user accidently double clicks

### Disable button

Simply disable the button on the first click. When the task completes, enable the button.

### Post to queue

If your particular choice of GUI framework has a problem with the clicks leaking through, then each click could post to a queue.

On every click, post an object (perhaps a `Runnable`/`Callable`) to a capacity-restricted queue by way of the [`offer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer(E)) method.

If your queue is set to a capacity limit of one, then calling `offer` on a second element will be refused, returning `false`.

Do not remove the first object from the queue until its job is done.

### Server-side

If you really cannot address the problem at the source, the client, you could collect every post into an expiring cache. When the server receives a post, it first checks the cache for a match. If matched, refuse/ignore the post. If no match, add the post to the cache, and then process that post.

You will find an expiring cache implementation in [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava), and perhaps in [*Eclipse Collections*](https://eclipse.dev/collections/). Apparently Spring also [offers caching](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-setting-ttl-value-cache) with a Time-To-Live feature.

You could write your own with a background thread that clears the cache repeatedly. But I would recommend using an existing one from a library that is already written, tested, and deployed.

Both approaches to an expiring cache are discussed at: [*Java time-based map/cache with expiring keys*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3802370/642706)

Comment: That is not quite what I need. I don't want to prohibit all concurrency. I just want to prevent concurrent calls with the same unique id.

Comment: @pbuchheit You said the problem is preventing rapid multiple clicks of a button by the user. If every click is posted to a capacity-limited queue, the extra clicks will be ignored. How does that not address your issue?

Comment: I can't simply have a one item queue since there are potentially multiple users who should be able to make concurrent requests, as long as each request is for a different object. What I need to prevent is concurrent requests with the SAME object.

Comment: @pbuchheit There would be one queue per user (or one disabled button per user) in the app, where they are clicking the button.